# Rewrite index.php?lang=1 to index-en.html

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

my urls are index.php?lang=1, index.php?lang=2, etc for each home language
and i want to rewrite it to index-en.html, index-de.html, etc

I missed something, it doesn't work.
the second other rule is messing up, don't know.
here is my code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.php?lang=1$ index-en.php [QSA, L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^[^/\.]+(\.html)?$  index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: How do you plan to correlate the numbers on the query string e.g. `lang=1` to index-en.html or index.de.html? It really won't be dynamic if you aren't using matching values.

Comment: by not doing it dynamically ;) as it only concerns my 2 (home) pages, so i thought... 2 rules... oh, not a big deal ;).

Comment: I see. I thought you might have more languages. So doing each one would be more work for you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`, you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable in a condition. So instead of:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?lang=1$ index-en.php [QSA, L]
```

You want:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=1$ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index-en.php? [L]
```

You also don't want that space inside the brackets. It'll confuse mod_rewrite and make it think the rewrite flags end with `,`.